# IP Range to CIDR conversion in Python?

Tags: python

How can I get a CIDR notation representing a range of IP addresses, given the start and end IP addresses of the range, in Python? I can find CIDR to IP Range but cannot find any code for the reverse.

Example of the desired output:

```
startip = '63.223.64.0'
endip = '63.223.127.255'

return '63.223.64.0/18'
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You may use `iprange_to_cidrs` provided by [netaddr](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netaddr) module. Example:

```sh
pip install netaddr
```

```py
import netaddr
cidrs = netaddr.iprange_to_cidrs(startip, endip)
```

Here are the official docs: https://netaddr.readthedocs.io/

Comment: cidrs = netaddr.ip_range_to_cidrs(ip1 , ip2 )
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ip_range_to_cidrs'

Comment: @ChrisHall Sorry for the typo, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Here's how to do it in Python3:  from ipaddress import ip_address, summarize_address_range; start,end = ip_address(startip), ip_address(endip); return summarize_address_range(start,end).

Comment: To tidy up @JJC's answer for `python 2.7`.................................................................................................

```from ipaddress import ip_address,summarize_address_range;
summarize_address_range(ip_address(unicode(startip)), ip_address(unicode(endip)))```

Answer (score 39):

Starting Python 3.3 the bundled [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) can provide what you want. The function [summarize_address_range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.summarize_address_range) returns an iterator with the networks resulting from the start, end you specify:

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> startip = ipaddress.IPv4Address('63.223.64.0')
>>> endip = ipaddress.IPv4Address('63.223.127.255')
>>> [ipaddr for ipaddr in ipaddress.summarize_address_range(startip, endip)]
[IPv4Network('63.223.64.0/18')]
```

Comment: No external dependencies. Love it!

Comment: Yes.. This should have been the accepted answer.. never the less still very helpful..

Comment: Only it doesn't give you just 1 cidr, it gives you at least 1.

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you want only 1 cidr (instead of multiple cidr's) you'll need to use the `spanning_cidr` function from either [`netaddr`](https://netaddr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/netaddr/ip.html#spanning_cidr)

`pip install netaddr`

```py
from netaddr import spanning_cidr
spanning_cidr([startip, endip])
```

or [`spanning_cidr`](https://github.com/moskrc/spanning-cidr)

`pip install spanning-cidr`

```py
from spanning_cidr import spanning_cidr
spanning_cidr([startip, endip])
```

Here is the difference...

```py
>>> from ipaddress import IPv4Address, summarize_address_range
>>> from netaddr import spanning_cidr
>>>
>>> startip = IPv4Address('63.223.64.0')
>>> endip = IPv4Address('63.224.127.255')
>>> list(summarize_address_range(startip, endip))
[IPv4Network('63.223.64.0/18'),
 IPv4Network('63.223.128.0/17'),
 IPv4Network('63.224.0.0/17')]
>>>
>>> spanning_cidr([startip, endip])
IPNetwork('63.223.64.0/18')
```