# Checking an IP Address against an CIDR range in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, geolite2

I've got a problem i have been trying to work out I have googled a few things that are similar to what i want to do but can't work out exactly how to do it,

I have around 250M ip address's and i want to look that up against the maxmind geolite2 data so that i can tell what country each IP-address originates from,

I have imported all the data into my Redshift cluster with talend,

```
table a has ID and 'ipaddress' ie 10.0.0.5
table b (maxmind) has country name and IP range as expressed as 10.0.0.0/24
```

how could i use Redshift SQL to match these two considering the size of my source data source?

edit: heres the link to the geolite2 data https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/

Comment: Don't know if redshift does, but Postgres supports the "contains" operator for the `inet` data type: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-net.html that operator can also make use of an index on the columns

Comment: I tried this to no avail  turns out redshift does not support either of these

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using Amazon Redshift's ability to [Import Custom Python Library Modules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-python-language-support.html) to load the [netaddr library](https://pythonhosted.org/netaddr/tutorial_01.html). Then, you could use the library within a User Defined Function written in Python.

See also: [IP Range to CIDR conversion in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214441/ip-range-to-cidr-conversion-in-python)