# how to write a range from 1 to 254 using CIDR notation?

Tags: python, networking, ip, scapy, cidr

hello i am trying to make an app that shows all the connected devices to the network
how can write the range from 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.0.255 in CIDR notation ?
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214441/ip-range-to-cidr-conversion-in-python

Comment: Hi Esra, welcome to StackOverflow. Please include any code that you've tried already and the errors that you're encountering.

Comment: all right, I will edit the post please check it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IP Range to CIDR conversion in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214441/ip-range-to-cidr-conversion-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Scapy understands CIDR notation in IP address fields by automatically converting it to a [`Net`](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.base_classes.html#scapy.base_classes.Net) object:

```
>>> import scapy.all as scapy
>>> scapy.Net("192.168.0.1/24")
Net("192.168.0.1/24")
>>> list(_)
['192.168.0.0',
 '192.168.0.1',
 '192.168.0.2',
 '192.168.0.3',
 ...
```

but in your example you can just do

```
>>> eth = scapy.Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
>>> arp = scapy.ARP(pdst="192.168.0.1/24")
>>> scapy.srp(eth / arp, timeout=5)[0]
```

since, as I said, it's converted behind the scenes.