# How to convert CIDR to list of IPs

Tags: python

This is a file I have:

```
1.1.1.1/26
2.2.2.2/28
3.3.3.3/29
4.4.4.4/30
```

I want to convert all of these subnets to IPs.

```
import ipaddress
with open('subnets.txt', 'r') as file1:
    the_ip=file1.read()
    for ip in ipaddress.ip_network(the_ip):
        print(f'IP: {ip}')
```

This is what I'm trying to do but I get this error:

> ValueError: "['1.1.1.1/26', '2.2.2.2/28', '3.3.3.3/29', '4.4.4.4/30']"
> does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 network

This is the list I tried making:

```
ips_list = ['1.1.1.1/26', '2.2.2.2/28', '3.3.3.3/29', '4.4.4.4/30']
```

This is the error:

```
"ips_list = ['1.1.1.1/26', '2.2.2.2/28', '3.3.3.3/29', '4.4.4.4/30']" does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 network
```

How can I convert subnets to list of IPs?

I googled the errors and the how-tos, but none of them worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IP Range to CIDR conversion in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214441/ip-range-to-cidr-conversion-in-python)

Comment: ipaddress.ip_network() function expects a single IP network or CIDR string as its argument, not a list. I think you can iterate over the list of subnets and pass each one to the function individually

Comment: @Daviid no, that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @AchrafBenSalah thanks, o didn't know that. I'll try that iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the file line by line, not at once:

```
import ipaddress
with open('subnets.txt', 'r') as file1:
    for netw in file1:
        print(f"Network: {netw}")
        for ip in ipaddress.ip_network(netw.strip()):
            print(f"  IP: {ip}")
```